# Automatically generating sequential ids in a Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, mariadb, galera

I have a Galera cluster with 3 nodes. On it, there are several tables, let's for the sake of argument assume some of them are:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE item     (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT);
```

I want ids in the `customer` table to be as close to sequential (1, 2, 3...) as possible. 
So far, it looks like ids increment by 3 per new customer. I'd like to make it 1.

On the other hand, the values of ids in the `item` table don't matter, but it should be possible to insert into this table with minimal or no locking.

Is it possible to have sequential ids in a Galera cluster, or at least almost sequential?

Comment: @BK435 Thanks, I know about it. What I'm looking for is a way to circumvent it.

Comment: If you stick with `AUTO_INCREMENT` functionality you won't get those sequential values that you expect.
The only solution I see is to delete the `AUTO_INCREMENT` from the table definition and implement that functionality in your application yourself.
For example, when inserting a new row in the `customer` table, first you run a `SELECT MAX(id) FROM customer`. Add 1 to that MAX and use that value on the `INSERT` query into the `customer` table.

Comment: @CiprianStoica - Beware.  If another connection on another node sneaks in and does the same thing, you could get a duplicate key (or, more likely, an error on `COMMIT`).